# vb.net weight scale tcpip not getting data

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient

i am new to vb.net 2008 to get data from weigh scale using tcpclient(). below mentioned code is able to connect with machine but not getting the data. But hyperterminal is able to get data.

I searched most of the post but may coding exist only for serial port connection.

**Output MsgBox :** 
Received: {0}

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Public Sub Connect(ByVal server As [String], ByVal _Ports As Int32, ByVal message As [String])
        Try
            ' Create a TcpClient. 
            ' Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer  
            ' connected to the same address as specified by the server, port 
            ' combination. 
            Dim port As Int32 = _Ports
            Dim client As New TcpClient()
            'Dim client As New TcpClient(server, port)
            client.Connect(server, port)
            If client.Client.Connected Then TextBox3.Text = "Connected"

            ' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array. 
            Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)

            ' Get a client stream for reading and writing. 
            '  Stream stream = client.GetStream(); 
            Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
            Dim Buffer(client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte

            ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

            'Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message)
            MsgBox("Sent: {0} " & message)
            ' Receive the TcpServer.response. 
            ' Buffer to store the response bytes.
            data = New [Byte](2047) {}

            'MsgBox("Response Byte - " & data.Length)

            ' String to store the response ASCII representation. 
            Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty

            ' Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes. 
            Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
            'Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData)
            MsgBox("Received: {0} " & responseData)

            ' Close everything.
            stream.Close()
            client.Close()
        Catch e As ArgumentNullException
            'Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e)
            MsgBox("ArgumentNullException: {0}" & e.Message)
        Catch e As SocketException
            'Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e)
            MsgBox("SocketException: {0}" & e.Message)
        End Try

        MsgBox("Got to this point in code")

        'Console.WriteLine(ControlChars.Cr + " Press Enter to continue...")
        'Console.Read()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your error log has the placeholder {0} in it, what do you get if you use   MsgBox($"Received: {0} " & responseData)

Comment: i got empty response data as a output. but machine status got connected. but only thing is not receiving the data.

Comment: You need to look up some documentation for your weight scale. There is no guarantee that the data is sent in plain text. It may contain control characters or numbers represented by a sequence of bytes (or both).

Comment: Side note: `{0}` is used as a placeholder for functions like [`String.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object_). You're using regular string concatenation so `{0}` becomes part of the string instead of being replaced with a value. You should just remove it from your strings altogether.

Comment: thanks @VisualVincent, I am new to vb.net. i will check with weight scale support persons and i will update the control character.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
MsgBox("Received: {0} " & responseData)
```

...does not automatically replace `{0}` with the value of `responseData`.

The `{0}` placeholder is used with the `String.Format()` function. Change your code to this, in all applicable places, and check the result:

```
' Let's also get rid of the legacy VB6 MsgBox() function:
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Received: {0} ", responseData))
```

Also, what's with the square brackets around some data types (i.e. [String])? They aren't needed.

Comment: FWIW while that will get rid of the `{0}`, it won't change the result. The OP already appends `responseData` in the message box so he/she should see it despite not using `String.Format()`. But since only `Received {0}` is shown, either no data is received or it starts with a null character.